# how to make radio button values to push only once in to an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[My plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/R4mdZr/)

how to make radio button values to push only once in to an array?

**My Code**

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function(clickedItem) {
    var value = clickedItem;
      var index = $scope.selected_ingrediants.indexOf(value);
      if (index === -1) {
        $scope.selected_ingrediants.push(value);
      } else {
        $scope.selected_ingrediants.splice(index, 1);
      }

  }
```

Comment: Edited.. I think this site is intended for helping developers I'm new in angular.js.. My purpose of this question was I want only one value got pushed to array but in my case the previously selected values are of too pushing to array

Comment: For a single radio group the previously selected values are of pushing if I make a change how to avoid those?.. Got my question?

Comment: perhaps a better solution (A.K.A. "_the angular way_") would be [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) (see [radio example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)) - one model for the size, one model for toppings (*cheese* / *extra cheese* / *veggy*)...

Comment: You are always pushing new value on ng-click="toggleSelection(get_ing_n)". But where you are removing previously  checked value?

Comment: Yes for checkbok it's working fine.. Wondering how to do same for radio too

Comment: Checkbox and radio buttons will not behave same. better to write separate functions for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/XKni4rsartk0iKLBM8JN?p=preview)

You need to tell the toggleSelection function that the selection is a radio or a checkbok and handle accordingly

**Controller**

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function(clickedItem, selectOne) {
var value = clickedItem;

if(selectOne){
  var existing = $scope.selected_ingrediants.filter(function(ing){
    return ing.ingredientTypeId === value.ingredientTypeId;
  })[0];
  var hasSelectionIdx = $scope.selected_ingrediants.indexOf(existing);
  if (hasSelectionIdx === -1) {
    $scope.selected_ingrediants.push(value);
  } else {
    $scope.selected_ingrediants.splice(hasSelectionIdx, 1, value);
  }
}else{
  var hasIngredientIdx = $scope.selected_ingrediants.indexOf(value);
  if (hasIngredientIdx === -1) {
    $scope.selected_ingrediants.push(value);
  } else {
    $scope.selected_ingrediants.splice(hasIngredientIdx, 1);
  }
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="get_ingredientTypeName_values in get_ing_value.ingredientTypeList">
  {{get_ingredientTypeName_values.ingredientTypeName}}

   <div >
  <ul ng-show="get_ingredientTypeName_values.minVal == 1" ng-repeat="get_ing_n in get_ingredientTypeName_values.ingredientList">
    <li> <input type="radio" name="{{get_ing_n.ingredientTypeId}}" ng-click="toggleSelection(get_ing_n, true)">{{get_ing_n.ingredientName}},{{get_ing_n.ingredientPrice}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div >
  <ul ng-show="get_ingredientTypeName_values.minVal == null" ng-repeat="get_ing_n in get_ingredientTypeName_values.ingredientList">
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="{{get_ing_n.ingredientTypeId}}" ng-click="toggleSelection(get_ing_n, false)">{{get_ing_n.ingredientName}},{{get_ing_n.ingredientPrice}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are pushing the radio value whenever the radio button is clicked.

```
ng-click="toggleSelection(get_ing_n)"
```

The right way to do it would be pushing the value only when clicking on submit button, and instead of getting the value with ng-click, you should use ng-value, as shown in the AngularJS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Comment: Could you post a plunker?